# How is the Arrays.hashCode implemented?

Tags: java, hash

I was reading the code for the `Arrays.hashCode` provided below,

```
public static int hashCode(Object a[]) {
        if (a == null)
            return 0;

        int result = 1;

        for (Object element : a)
            result = 31 * result + (element == null ? 0 : element.hashCode());

        return result;
    }
```

I find it's not as clear as for why `31` is chosen for the hashing.

Secondly, the `element.hashCode()` send me to the `Object` class that defines it:

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public native int hashCode();
```

How the `element.hashCode()` is calculaed for the each iteration?

Thank you.

Comment: `I find it's not as clear as for why 31 is chosen for the hashing.` because its prime.

Comment: @tkausl There many smaller primes as well, for example, why the `17` is not chosen? There might be some strong reasoning behind.

Comment: It shows why using  magic-numbers is not a good practice.

Comment: @AmitBera That link explain well. Shortly, Java choose 31 to optimize calculating costs.

Comment: "How the element.hashCode() is calculaed" - each class can implement (override) the `hashCode` method; e.g. `Integer` just returns its value

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I think the question is what does `native` mean and also what a hotspot intrinsic candidate is? i.e. no one is _forced_ to override `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the book *Effective Java:*

> The value 31 was chosen because it is an odd prime. If it were even and the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost, as multiplication by 2 is equivalent to shifting. The advantage of using a prime is less clear, but it is traditional. A nice property of 31 is that the multiplication can be replaced by a shift and a subtraction for better performance: 31 * i == (i << 5) - i. Modern VMs do this sort of optimization automatically.

Comment: I tested for small numbers and still find the `(i << 5) - i` is faster